# why are new dim added when coding "padding mask"

Tags: tensorflow2.0, transformer-model

https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer?hl=en
In the Mask part of tf's official document "Transformer model for language understanding",why newaix should be added and why must be added here?

```
def create_padding_mask(seq):
  seq = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(seq, 0), tf.float32)

  return seq[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

As this mask is then used in `scaled_dot_product_attention` function, mapping the padded positions' logits to $-\infty$ after dot product, where the shape of the dot product is (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_q, seq_len_k). The way it does this is adding $-\infty * mask$ to the dot product, so the mask need to be broadcastable to the dot product. And the  broadcasting rule used by tensorflow is quite similar to [numpy's](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when

they are equal, or
one of them is 1
```

So the axis 1 and 2 are added here in the mask to make it broadcastable.

Comment: Thanks very much. After that,i‘ve read the following code and learned it.My understanding is like your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.